# How can i remove duplicate orders in backend magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I am Stuck in a big problem.
when i order a product magento backend shows me duplicate order details each time.
[image]

what could be the reason behind it?

Comment: Did you alter the order collection query ?

Comment: i think somewhere i did the duplicasy i dont know where

Comment: If you had altered the query, you have to find it, in order to correct the listing.